# Add items into a MovieClip in a specific direction

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'd like to add MovieClips inside a container MovieClip in a specific order. (left to right, up to down).

for example: In flex I have Hbox, VBox, HGroup, VGroup. Do I have any implementation like that in flash?

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
myMC.x = prevMC.x + prevMC.width + spacing;

prevMC = myMC;

...
```

You can write a base class, however, that encapsulates this, which is what the Flex team did.